# What's the most appropriate way to reuse the Exec task in gradle for common command line operations?

Tags: plugins, gradle

I'm writing a gradle build file that will install a basic development domain for our product. Essentially all of the real code is going to be in custom plugins and custom tasks. Several of the steps involved are fairly repetitive (multiple sudo calls, multiple user adds) and I would like to encapsulate the common stuff into a task.

For example:

```groovy
task('addDBUser', type:AddUser) {
    username = joeUser
}

task('startService', type:SudoExec) {
    workingDir = "not/too/relevant"
    commandLine = "/etc/init.d/coolService start"
}
```

I'd like to reuse the various functionality that Exec gets me (stdin, stdout, etc.) as tidily as possible, while supplying the boilerplate ("sudo ...") automatically. I'm pretty sure I can just extend Exec instead of DefaultTask, but I don't know a standard way of triggering actual action. It seems easy to modify the commandLine property with what I need, but there's no generic "run()" or the like to use when I want Exec to actually go.

Do I open up Exec to identify which method is it's work method and then invoke it directly? Or is there a more generic way of accomplishing my goal?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I can't write better questions if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I agree with Josh. I also hate when somebody gives downvote without any reason. I think that the best will be if comment will be needed for downvote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see which method is executed for a task you can check the sources of `Exec` and search for a method marked with `@TaskAction`. It turns out that it's the `exec()` method but in general you don't want to be calling task actions manually but let Gradle do it for you. The best idea in my opinion is to add methods/setters to your custom tasks. It might look like that:

```groovy
task addUser(type: AddUser) {
    username = 'fromGradle'
}


class SudoExec extends Exec {

    void sudoCommand(Object... arguments) {
        executable 'sudo'
        args = arguments.toList()
    }
}

class AddUser extends SudoExec {

    void setUsername(String username) {
        sudoCommand('useradd', username)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, and I don't need to know what method the Exec command uses because that method and its @TaskAction annotation will both be inherited. As long as I modify the expected values, Gradle will connect the dots for me.When I wrote this question I had a feeling it would be something relatively basic about OO that I was just not getting to click. (It was a long week here in the greater Boston metro area.) Thanks for being patient!

Comment: You are right about not having to know the internals of `Exec` and Gradle connecting the dots for you. No problem and good luck!

Comment: This is bad solution because it breaks your incapsulation. In general you don't want to let your users know that this task is just a basic Exec task and even more - you don't want them to mess with it's parameters, such as executable or args, which are exposed with inheritance.

Comment: The thing you are referring to is called encapsulation, not incapsulation. And yes, this solution is not the best as ideally don't want to expose the fact that it's an extended `Exec` task but unfortunately given the way task classes are designed in Gradle I don't think reuse of `Exec` task without extending from it is possible. Or maybe you know how this can be solved in another way?

Answer (score 1):

This code is able to handle multiple parameters, as it doesn't hook into setters of any specific parameters, but uses lazy GString evaluation.

```
task vagrantfile (type:Vagrantfile) {
    account 'vagrant'
    password 'vagrant'
}

class Vagrantfile extends Copy {
    String account
    String password

    def Vagrantfile() {
        from 'templates/'
        into 'build/'
        include 'Vagrantfile.ubuntu.tpl'
        rename {'Vagrantfile'}
        expand (account:"${->account}", password:"${->password}")
    }
}
```